# Effect of increasing the current in a current carrying straight conductor on a compass?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields

why the deflection(why there is change in direction) increases with increased current in a straight metal  conductor ?
[image]

in figure 2 , the magnetic fields are closely packed due to high current but still the  deflection would remain the same. But why do we say that the compass deflection is by more angle

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to place the compass to the magnetic North (or South, but we'll assume North) of the wire, at a point P (say). With no current in the wire, the Earth's magnetic field (horizontal component) will make the compass needle point North, that is in the direction of the Earth's magnetic field.

When you turn on the current in the wire it will generate the magnetic field that you have shown in your diagrams. At P this field will be to the West. Magnetic field strength is a vector quantity, so the Earth's field and the wire's field at each point will add like vectors. At point P the resultant field will therefore be West of North. [You should draw a vector addition diagram to show this.] The vector diagram will show that at P the deflection, $\theta$, from North of the compass needle is given by
$$\tan \theta=\frac {\text{field at P due to wire}}{\text{Earth's field (horizontal component)}}$$

If you increase the current in the wire, the wire's field will increase in magnitude, and you will see from your vector diagram that the resultant field at P is *further* West of North, so the compass deflection will have increased.

If the wire's field at P is very much larger than the Earth's field, the compass needle will point almost (but not quite) due West.